# Pyinstaller error building Qt Application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller, pyqtgraph

I am building an exe from a PyQt+pyqtgraph project.
Everything is set correctly, also in the .spec file, since i correctly built a version of the software running pyinstaller.
Now, I did some modifications to my project, but I am not able to build it anymore.
Pyinstaller returns:

```
PyInstaller.isolated._parent.SubprocessDiedError: Child process died calling _collect_submodules() with args=('pyqtgraph.canvas', 'ignore') and kwargs={}. Its exit code was 3221226505.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed in two steps:

1. adding pyqtgraph.canvas to hidden imports in .spec file. Still not working.
2. checking installed packages with `pip list`, i found out that both PyQt5 and PyQt6 were installed. Hence I uninstalled PyQt6.

Then everything went ok.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after upgrading to Python 3.12.
I don't know why, but the build works when I pin my PyQt6 version to 6.5.3, but then pyqtgraph complains on runtime that it cannot find appropriate Qt bindings. I have temporarily fixed this by overwriting the `_internal/PyQt6` folder (I am using --onedir) with the one I get from building with Python 3.11 with the latest PyQt (6.6.1).

Edit: there seems to be a related [github issue](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/2838).

Edit 2: this was fixed in [pyqtgraph 0.13.4](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/2934).